# 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: ios, quickblox

In my application this error coming randomly when i send attachment(like Image and video) to other user,it crashes.

I am using **Quickblox** SDK.

This is the error..

> NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1
>   beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

```
        2016-04-26 10:22:50.510 Sample-VideoChat[1027:12093] *** Terminating  app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:     '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

  enter code here
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
 {
     NSLog(@"self.chatSections....%@",self.chatSections);
     return [self.chatSections count];
 }


 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(QMChatCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

    QBChatMessage *messageItem = [self messageForIndexPath:indexPath];

      NSRange textRange =[messageItem.text rangeOfString:@"https://api.quickblox.com/blobs/"];

     Class class = [self viewClassForItem:messageItem];
    NSString *itemIdentifier = [class cellReuseIdentifier];

     QMChatCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:itemIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.avatarView.tag = 0;

  if ((messageItem.attachments.count != 0) && textRange.location != NSNotFound) 
{

       QBChatAttachment* attachment = [[QBChatAttachment alloc] init];
         attachment.ID = @"3565772";
         attachment.url = messageItem.text;
         attachment.type = @"image";

         [cell.avatarView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:attachment.url] placeholder:nil options:SDWebImageContinueInBackground progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
     {
     } completedBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
     {
         cell.avatarView.tag = 4592;
     }];
}

cell.transform = self.collectionView.transform;

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];
singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;

[self collectionView:collectionView configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;
   }

 - (QBChatMessage *)messageForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
         if (indexPath.item == NSNotFound) {
          // If the update item's index path has an "item" value of NSNotFound, it means it was a section update, not an individual item.
        return nil;
     }

      QMChatSection *currentSection = self.chatSections[indexPath.section];
     return currentSection.messages[indexPath.item];
     }
```

Comment: Add some code to solve this error.@preeti patel

Comment: You can find code below the error.

Comment: Try adding an exception breakpoint (Add Exception Breakpoint) to debug where the exception occures. It does mean you are trying to access an object which is not in the index of array.

Comment: In this method  - (QBChatMessage *)messageForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath getting error to return currentSection. But sometimes it execute code.

Comment: your item value should be nil, so app is carsh. plz check your item value.

Comment: Please check you have values in 'self.chatSections' and 'currentSection.messages' before doing the further operations

Comment: @preetipatel Please check your method (Number of item in collection view).
i think you created number of item with different array count which you use in cell for item

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try adding an all-exception breakpoint (Add Exception Breakpoint) to debug where the exception occures. It does mean you are trying to access an object which is not in the index of array.

Best to find what is causing problem is to raise all exceptions before app crashes.

[image]i

Comment: You, you save my day :)

Comment: This does indeed reveal the issue immediately. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

**Static cells,**
I had the same issue. So, I just replaced the tableView content type

"Static cell" to "Dynamic prototypes".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (item != nil && item.count != 0) {
    QMChatSection *currentSection = self.chatSections[indexPath.section];
    return currentSection.messages[indexPath.item];
}
```

Comment: @preetipatel Please check your method (Number of item in collection view).
i think you created number of item with different array count which you use in cell for item

Answer (score 0):

You can make check like this, check for the value before you try to access the index

```
  if (self.chatSections.count > 0) {
        QMChatSection *currentSection = self.chatSections[indexPath.section];
        if (currentSection.messages.count > 0){
            return currentSection.messages[indexPath.item];
        }else {
            return nil;
        }
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
```

If you are creating your own code with Quickblox you can refer their demo implementation as for me it works proper

Comment: This code is not working for me, showing same error.

Comment: @preetipatel ok , are you using the quickblox sample demo or created your new demo, if you are using same please provide link so we can check in the code itself

Comment: I have created my own with the help of sample demo